# Rebuilding a packet to inject via pcap

Tags: c, code-injection, pcap, tcpdump

Here is the situation: in my scenario I have, 3 computers, A, B and C.

Computer A sends data to computer B. Computer B captures these packets with pcap, appends the headers, redoes the checksums, and injects it out another ethernet interface to computer C. So basically A sends to C, though through C's point of view, the data is coming from computer B.

My problem is this: following TCPDUMP's tutorial on dissecting a captured packet, I've learned to calculate offsets and using typecasting to obtain ethernet, ip, and tcp header structures. The method of doing so is shown below:

```
ethernet = (struct sniff_ethernet*)(packet);
ip = (struct sniff_ip*)(packet + SIZE_ETHERNET);
size_ip = IP_HL(ip)*4;
if (size_ip < 20) {
    printf("   * Invalid IP header length: %u bytes\n", size_ip);
    return;
}
tcp = (struct sniff_tcp*)(packet + SIZE_ETHERNET + size_ip);
size_tcp = TH_OFF(tcp)*4;
if (size_tcp < 20) {
    printf("   * Invalid TCP header length: %u bytes\n", size_tcp);
    return;
}
payload = (u_char *)(packet + SIZE_ETHERNET + size_ip + size_tcp);
```

Because I want to inject the captured packet to send it from computer B to computer C, I must modify some of the source/destination information and recalculate the checksum when I'm done. However, my issue is, since this data is now separated into structures of ethernet header, IP header, and TCP headers, how do I put it back together into a `u_char` that `pcap_inject` can use?

Is it possible to do some sort of concatenation here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code I see here, you're not actually dissecting the memory that `libpcap` captured for you. Each of the casting operations simply tells the compiler how you intend to treat the bytes starting from a pointer -- what size those objects are, what offsets to find which pieces of data and how long they are.

If you modify this memory through those pointers, you've modified the one and only copy of it in the process memory -- and can use some of the "more basic" pointers to hand the entire block of memory to `sendmsg(2)` or whatever without needing to reassemble the data -- you never took it apart.

**Update**

To inject the packets back on the network you need to use the `raw(7)` socket type; the `IPPROTO_RAW` socket option is required to send TCP packets through a `raw(7)` socket -- otherwise, *all* TCP packets would be directed to the `raw(7)` socket you open, making networking on the machine difficult to use.

The `raw(7)` sockets will perform some re-calculation tasks for you:

```
   A protocol of IPPROTO_RAW implies enabled IP_HDRINCL and is
   able to send any IP protocol that is specified in the passed
   header.  Receiving of all IP protocols via IPPROTO_RAW is not
   possible using raw sockets.

          ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
          │IP Header fields modified on sending by IP_HDRINCL │
          ├──────────────────────┬────────────────────────────┤
          │IP Checksum           │Always filled in.           │
          ├──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
          │Source Address        │Filled in when zero.        │
          ├──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
          │Packet Id             │Filled in when zero.        │
          ├──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
          │Total Length          │Always filled in.           │
          └──────────────────────+────────────────────────────┘

   If IP_HDRINCL is specified and the IP header has a nonzero
   destination address then the destination address of the
   socket is used to route the packet.  When MSG_DONTROUTE is
   specified, the destination address should refer to a local
   interface, otherwise a routing table lookup is done anyway
   but gatewayed routes are ignored.

   If IP_HDRINCL isn't set, then IP header options can be set on
   raw sockets with setsockopt(2); see ip(7) for more
   information.
```

Let the kernel re-calculate whatever it is willing to do for you.

Comment: I only copied a snippet of the tutorial. The tutorial is here: http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html and the code is here:http://www.tcpdump.org/sniffex.c

anyhow, what they seem to be doing is filling out the structures for each type of header by doing the type casting. So I was wondering if there is some sort of easy reverse process i can do to reconstruct a packet and give it to the injector function.

sorry if what I'm asking seems to be kind of misinformed. I'm doing this for a senior design project in EE. CS and code related stuff is really something I'm picking up.

Comment: Ah. I don't see any _modification_ there, but I also didn't see any code that looked like it actually made copies of the data either.

Comment: I pressed enter and accidentally posted prematurely. I was editing the comment to make room for more stuff.

Comment: You've definitely found something out-of-the-way to try to implement, good work there. :) What are you _really_ trying to do? I'm beginning to think that there might be better tools.

Comment: Well, my the goal of my project is to be able to let a client computer fall asleep while giving the illusion that it is still present on the network. So the code I am writing is to be run on a low power device that sits between the network and the client. When the client is on, all it needs to do is capture, fix headers, inject  to client (forwarding). if the client is asleep, I cache the data that needs to be fwded, wake client via magic packet, then send cached data. I know I could just let the device be a NAT but I want other boxes to be able to talk as if there were no intermediate device.

Comment: Awesome device. Sign me up for a big pile of them. :) The [`minewt`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/minewt.1.html) tool provides NAT (and MAT -- MAC Address Translation) functionality entirely in userspace -- and [`Ettercap`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ettercap_(computing)) does a _lot_ of sneaky man-in-the-middle networking tricks. They might prove a useful source of inspiration or code (depending upon licenses).

Comment: so would it be completely ill advised to do injection using pcap's functions? Also I guess it'd be fine to let the kernel handle some of it. I donno why I was under the impression that I needed to build something all by myself!

Comment: oh and thanks for the help (and interest!). :) I'll let you know if this thing ends up working

Comment: After reading through your updated message, this time on a computer and not on my cellphone, I'm still a little confused. So my ultimate goal is to use sendmsg() to send my packet to the client computer? What about the ethernet/ip headers? The ethernet header should now have source and destination be computer B and C respectively. IP header's source should be the origin's IP but the dest should be computer C's. How would I change this? via IP_HDRINCL? what parts of the captured packet would I send? Just the payload? and finally, how I fill out the parameters of a socket()?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was wrong -- I was under the impression that `libpcap` couldn't send packets itself. I hadn't heard about `pcap_inject()`, which definitely looks better than trying to implement the packet sending yourself. Definitely stick with `pcap_inject()`. :)

Comment: alright cool. I've actually gotten it down most of the way, (modifying the addresses so they're good). but I'm kind of stuck calculating the IP checksums. I have code that I'm going to lift from the internet that (i hope) calculates the ip header sum correctly. It takes in the header and the header length as parameters. However, the funny typecasting that I'm doing doesn't seem to be compatible. I'm checking the original checksum vs the calculated and it never matches... I'm thinking it's got to do with the type casting. I wish i could type more, but the word count limit...

Comment: Don't hesitate to open a new question. :)

Comment: So i did :) here's the new question: