# Caching packets captured from pcap

Tags: c, caching, packet, pcap

This is a follow-up question to this:
[Rebuilding a packet to inject via pcap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193281/rebuilding-a-packet-to-inject-via-pcap)

What I want to accomplish:

1. functionA: Capture packets with pcap. Modify source/destination addresses. Recalculate checksums. Inject with pcap.
2. functionB: Create two threads. Thread 1 sends a magic packet to wake sleeping client. Thread 2 captures packets with pcap and caches the packets into an array of u_char *'s, since pcap puts the packet data serially into "u_char * packet". When both threads terminate, I then change the headers then inject each of the cached packets.

What I need help with:

1. functionA: I can do everything but calculate checksums. I tried to verify the original checksum by calculating it myself with a function but they never match. However, this issue is not as important because I don't need it to demo my final project. I understand that if IP checksums are incorrect, the receiving computer will discard the packet. But when I demo, so long as my client computer can be shown to have received this incorrect packet, I have proven my overall concept and will not fail. :)
2. functionB: I guess this is the more important problem. I don't know of an easy way to cache my captured packets. What I'm working on right now is as follows:

functionB creates a pointer to an array that stores u_char * called cachedPackets. So cachedPackets basically points to an array that stores "strings".

It'll be something like this? `u_char ** cachedPackets[100]`, enough array elements for 100 packets.

After this, I start two threads. Thread1 to wake my sleeping client. Thread2 to open another pcap session so no data is lost while client is waking. Thread1 is easy, I've already tested my send magic packet function independently. Thread2 is where I'm screwing up.

Thread2 eventually calls `int pcap_loop(pcap_t *p, int cut, pcap_handler callback, u_char *user)`.

callback is the function that will be run after each packet is captured. It is where I will be caching the packet into the array.

callback takes parameters `( u_char* user, 
                       const struct pcap_pkthdr* packet_header,
                       const u_char* packet_data )`

user is the same string in the 4th argument of pcap_loop.

So I was thinking, I could sneakily give my callback function the pointer to the array of string by type casting it.

`pcap_loop(asdf, asdf, callback, (u_char *)cachedPackets);`

Since I don't know how big the incoming packets will be, I'll dynamically allocate enough space in the callback function. I will also keep track of my position in the array with a static int.

this is what the callback looks like:

```
void cacheCall(u_char * user, const struct pcap_pkthdr * header, const u_char * packet)

    static int cacheindex = 0;

    u_char ** cachethis = (u_char **)user; 

    //u_char * cachething = *cachethis;
    (*cachethis)[cacheindex] = (u_char *) malloc(header->len); <--- 497


    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < header->len; i++)
    {
        (*cachethis)[cacheindex][i] = packet[i]; <-------------------503
    }

    //memcpy(cachething[cacheindex], packet, header->len);
    cacheindex++;
```

but when I compile, i get

```
497: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
503: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer
```

That was pretty longwinded, hopefully my knowledge of what I'm doing isn't completely misinformed. Any help would be awesome! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
u_char ** cachethis;
```

`cachethis` is a pointer-to-pointer-to-u_char.

So:

```
*cachethis
```

is a pointer-to-u_char, and:

```
(*cachethis)[i]
```

is a plain `u_char`.

So line 497 tries to store a pointer into an `u_char`, and line 503 tries to subscript a `u_char`, both of which are invalid.

Looks like what you want is simply:

```
cachethis[i]
```

and

```
cachethis[i][j]
```

Comment: Amazing! it compiled without a hitch, though I'm too scared to run it haha. Scared that i'll just segfault.

Comment: So just to be sure, when i use the for loop, with the correct code, I'm going to be storing all the u_chars in the u_char * packet into my cache right?

Comment: I admit I didn't read your post completely, just the error part, so I have no idea if the rest of what goes around that is ok. The fact that you're casting a `u_char*` to a `u_char**` is actually really suspicious. Rewrite your code so that you don't have to use pointer  casts and you should be safer. (And if you can, investigate the possibility of using a container library, or possibly C++ containers.)

Comment: Re your second comment: you will be storing into the memory area you allocated at line 497, yes.

Comment: alright thanks a lot. surprisingly my pthreads doesn't fail either. this is looking very good. thanks for your help!